# Adding Decimal point button to my calculator app

Tags: ios, swift, decimal, calculator

edit:

```
 @IBAction func decimal(_ sender: UIButton)
  {
      label.text = label.text! + String(decimal)
      numberOnScreen = Double(label.text!)!
      performingMath = true
      do {
      previousNumber = Double(self.label.text!)!

     }
   }
```

its still not adding the decimal to the number already pressed, instead its clearing the number and just changing the label to decimal. also its not performing the maths correctly

I would like to add a decimal point to my calculator.

Once I add the button in as an action how do I code it to work as a decimal point.
I want it coded in the same format iv coded the rest of the buttons.
I need it to display the previous number once pressed, and also to perform the math using the decimal, and display a Bool with the decimal.

im a beginner and self taught
I coded this following a tutorial but the tutorial didn't show how to add a decimal

could someone please help me program the decimal button.

```
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!


@IBAction func numbers(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    if performingMath == true
    {
        label.text = String(sender.tag-1)
        numberOnScreen = Double(label.text!)!
        performingMath = false
    }
    else
    {

    label.text = label.text! + String(sender.tag-1)
    numberOnScreen = Double(label.text!)!
}
}


@IBAction func button(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    if label.text != "" && sender.tag != 11 && sender.tag != 16
   {
    previousNumber = Double(label.text!)!

      if sender.tag == 12 //Divide
      {
        label.text = "/";
      }
    else if sender.tag == 13 //Multiply
      {
        label.text = "x";
      }
    else if sender.tag == 14 //Minus
      {
        label.text = "-";
      }
    else if sender.tag == 15 //Plus
      {
        label.text = "+";
      }

    operation = sender.tag
    performingMath = true;
}
   else if sender.tag == 16
{

if operation == 12
{
   label.text = String(previousNumber / numberOnScreen)
}


  else if operation == 13
{
   label.text = String(previousNumber * numberOnScreen)
}


  else if operation == 14
   {
   label.text = String(previousNumber - numberOnScreen)
   }


  else if operation == 15
   {
   label.text = String(previousNumber + numberOnScreen)
   }
    }
    else if sender.tag == 11
    {
        label.text = ""
        previousNumber = 0;
        numberOnScreen = 0;
        operation = 0;


}
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Comment: Append `"."` to your display `label` if it doesn't already have one. If your display label is empty, set your display `label` to `"0."`  Then do `numberOnScreen = Double(label.text!)!`.

Answer (score 0):

// Join this onto the bottom of your code, this is for the percentage button, NOTE the tag number on my percentage button is 18. remember you'll have to ctrl drag from the percentage button in the story board to the @IBAction func button(_ sender: UIButton)

```
    else if sender.tag == 11
            {
                label.text = ""
                previousNumber = 0;
                numberOnScreen = 0;
                operation = 0;
    }
            else if sender.tag == 18
            {
                if operation == 12
                {
                label.text = String(previousNumber / (previousNumber * (numberOnScreen / 100)))
                }
                else if operation == 13
                {
                    label.text = String(previousNumber * (previousNumber * (numberOnScreen / 100)))
                }
                else if operation == 14
                {
                    label.text = String(previousNumber - (previousNumber * (numberOnScreen / 100)))
                }
                else if operation == 15
                {
                    label.text = String(previousNumber + (previousNumber * (numberOnScreen / 100)))
                }
    }
}
```